# Subscribe to Graph Contact Subfolder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to subscribe to a particular folder within a user's contacts? In the previous Outlook API, I used the following resource:

[https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contactfolders/'xxxxxxxxx'/contacts](https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contactfolders/%27xxxxxxxxx%27/contacts)

What would the same be for the Microsoft Graph API call?

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) it's not possible to subscribe to contacts inside contact folder.

Anyway you can test it and try to create a subscription for contacts in a folder to be sure.

I would create the subscription this way:

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions`

JSON body:

```
{
    "changeType": "created",
    "notificationUrl": "<your_notification_url>",
    "resource": "me/contactFolders/{folder_id}/contacts",
    "expirationDateTime": "2022-11-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
    "clientState": "secretClientValue",
    "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```